# How to parse POST request from HTML+JS to ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, post

How to know what data came to my asp mvc app from html form (Post request)?

EDIT: I have static html file with js script and html form- wich should send mistakes to my aspx page.
I dont write server app yet,and want to know how to get and parse POST data from it.

Comment: its your `formcollection`  or if you have use model then post object is `Model`

Comment: You can parse the formcollection also If you thing that kind of data must be in Boolean or integer.

Comment: [About Stack Overflow] 
Get answers to practical, detailed questions.
Don't ask about...
Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use model in view or directly use html tools like textbox,radio

if you post the page jst write at top

```
<form method="post">
//html tags
</form>
```

in controller side jst add [httppost] attribute

example:---

in view

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="usern"/>
</form>
```

in controller

```
[httpost]
    public ActionResult Login(formcollection form)
    {
    string username=form["usern"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

You use like this in mvc

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm(Actionname, Controllername, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PenaltyForm" }))
            {

//Your html
    }
```

Then in the contoller you just use like this

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PenaltyfilterData(string startdate, string enddate, string Brand, string Warranty)
        {
           }
```

your form data will automatically mapped to the variables.